# '_File' is not a subtype of type 'String' in type cast

Tags: dart, flutter

When I try to upload a image to server from Flutter, this error occurres. I don't know how to pass the file to HTTP POSST method, but I took the image and got the file path using the `image_picker` plugin.

my file path is

> :I/flutter ( 9123): File:
>   '/storage/emulated/0/Android/data/com.example.myapp/files/Pictures/2798d03d-2c6b-4f80-8198-94866dfc45962028103221680196242.jpg'

my POST method is like ;

```
var response = await 

http.post("http://206.189.92.174:4000/API/Posts/Cube_Post_Submit",

    body :
       {
        'attachments' : files ,
       'User_Id' : "5acc5d6e1295332c28f7e205",
       'Cubes_Id' : jsonstring,
       'Post_Text' : "hello",
       'Post_Category' : "Story",
       'Post_Link': ""
       }
    );
   print(response.body);
```

error will be like this :

> [ERROR:flutter/shell/common/shell.cc(181)] Dart Error: Unhandled
>   exception: E/flutter ( 9123): type '_File' is not a subtype of type
>   'String' in type cast E/flutter ( 9123): #0      Object._as
>   (dart:core/runtime/libobject_patch.dart:74:25) E/flutter ( 9123): #1
>   CastMap.forEach. (dart:_internal/cast.dart:323:25)
>   E/flutter ( 9123): #2
>   __InternalLinkedHashMap&_HashVMBase&MapMixin&_LinkedHashMapMixin.forEach
>   (dart:collection/runtime/libcompact_hash.dart:365:8) E/flutter (
>   9123): #3      CastMap.forEach (dart:_internal/cast.dart:322:13)

Comment: Where does `http.` from `http.post` come from? Please add the import to your question.

Comment: i just used  void upload() async  method

Comment: Where does `files` come from?

Comment: " just used void upload() async method", sorry, no idea what that means.

Comment: this  method is working for without using a image ,,, but when i upload image only this error occurs

Comment: file is the camera picking image

Comment: But your code uses `files` not `file`

Comment: files only sorry

Comment: I think what you're looking for is a MultiPartRequest which will accept files. Check out this link: https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/package-http_http/MultipartRequest-class.html

Answer (score 1):

`files` in your code looks like plural, but your code doesn't show details.

This is the code to get a single file and this is sent as an array where more than one entry can be added
`[fileContentBase64]` or `[file1ContentBase64, file2ContentBase64, file3ContentBase64]`

```
import 'dart:convert';

...
var fileContent = file.readAsBytesSync();
var fileContentBase64 = base64.encode(fileContent); 

var response = await http.post("http://206.189.92.174:4000/API/Posts/Cube_Post_Submit",

    body :
       {
        'attachments' : [fileContentBase64] ,
       'User_Id' : "5acc5d6e1295332c28f7e205",
       'Cubes_Id' : jsonstring,
       'Post_Text' : "hello",
       'Post_Category' : "Story",
       'Post_Link': ""
       }
    );
   print(response.body);
```

Comment: Try executing `flutter clean` in the project directory and then try again.

Comment: when i used log for file message will be :

Comment: File: '/storage/emulated/0/Android/data/com.example.myapp/files/Pictures/2798d03d-2c6b-4f80-8198-94866dfc45962028103221680196242.jpg'

Comment: now its return type 'List<String>' is not a subtype of type 'String' in type cast

Comment: Please provide more complete information. What line does cause this error? Perhaps you want just `fileContentBase64` instead of `[fileContentBase64]`. I assumed a list because of plural `files` you used in your question.

Comment: Future getImage() async {
    var image = await ImagePicker.pickImage(source: ImageSource.camera);
    setState(() {
      files = image;
    });
  }

Answer (score 0):

You can use the detailed example [here](https://dev.to/carminezacc/advanced-flutter-networking-part-1-uploading-a-file-to-a-rest-api-from-flutter-using-a-multi-part-form-data-post-request-2ekm) that will help you achieve your goals.